# I want to delete from two tables but it doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, database

I have trying with this code...

```
> if($del == true)      
{

mysql_query("DELETE FROM member WHERE username = '".$del."' ");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM register WHERE username = '".$del."' ");

mysql_db_query("cbcompany");
echo 

"<script>

alert('Remove one member out :/(');window.location = 'member.php';

</script>";
}
```

but it just delete from only "register" table but in "member" table it didn't delete out
How I can do? 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: is `$del` a boolean `true`, or is it a username? If the latter, are you sure is it present in both tables, and not referenced via ID? Did you get any errors, or run the query from another tool to see whether the did work?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @lserni $del is a username. I try many way it not have show any errors :(

Comment: Your code lacks debugging. You don't check if the queries did succeed and how many rows were deleted, nor do you show the SQL query and the error message in case it failed. Fix that first if you want proper feedback here. Otherwise it's just guessing what is going wrong, which can be okay for the first five minutes, but as this takes longer, do proper error handling now with that code and provide exact results and mysql error messages in case of errors. Also provide the SQL queries verbatim.

Comment: As @Iserni said, if `$del` is boolean, then you likely can't check it in your SQL query.  If it is actually a username (to be deleted), you need to use `if ($del)` (same as `if (isset($del))`), not check wither it equals true.  

Also as others have said, mysql functions are frowned upon, perhaps look at a better way to get the username / user id and then check if $del = TRUE.

Comment: I found that it have a problem from table "member" that it can't delete from that table, how can I do?

Comment: Define "can't delete". Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? It's hard to help you when we're shooting blind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a link between the two tables where member is the parent and register is the child, you have to delete from the child table first.  The delete from member would fail in that case because you can't delete the parent until the child is deleted.

Another solution would be to have a cascading delete set up between the two tables so when you delete from member it deletes from register automatically.  I usually prefer to do it explicitly though - I don't like having automated deletes that are somewhat out of my control.

So quick answer, just reverse the order of your queries - do the register first, then member.

Comment: Can I use trigger? but I don't know how to write and use it on php :(
Thank you for your answer :')

Comment: In my opinion, there is never a good reason to use triggers!  Anything in the database that is hidden from view and can be forgotten about is a bad idea.  Just use my last suggestion - reverse the order of your queries.

Comment: I have try on reorder but it didn't work yet :( I don't know why TT___TT

Comment: Is there another table in your database that links to the member table?  You have to delete all child records first in other tables, assuming that's actually the problem here.

Comment: It relate just together and I found that it have a problem from table "member" that it can't delete from that table, how can I do?

Comment: Take a look at the comments below your original post first.  At this point you'll need more detailed information about why you can't delete before we can offer other suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if($del == true)      
{

mysql_query("DELETE FROM member WHERE username = '".$del."' ");

mysql_db_query("cbcompany");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM register WHERE username = '".$del."' ");

mysql_db_query("cbcompany");
}
```

Comment: Did you really just used JavaScript to redirect user to other page in your PHP code?! :D

Comment: Well, I just corrected the necessary part and did not pay attention to the rest of it. Thanks for your note. I have edited it.